# How to move all files whose contents begin with 0?

Tags: files, move, head

Here's a command to move all files whose *name* begin with 0 into a folder called zero :

```
mv [0]* zero
```

**Question**: What is a command for moving all files whose *contents* begin with 0 into a folder called zero?

Hopefully, there is a short command doing that also.

I know that the first character of the contents of a file is given by `head -c 1 filename`.

Comment: Do you only want ASCII zero (`0`) or do we need to consider https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbols_for_zero? Also, to move files whose names starts with zero, you don't need `[0]`, this works: `mv 0* zero/`.

Comment: @terdon The usual zero in a .txt file, so I guess the ASCII one.

Comment: Is this homework? (Not a problem if so, but it's courteous for it to be described as such.)

Comment: @ChrisDavies: it is not homework, I really need such a command. I have a folder of 100000 files and I need to move the ones whose contents start by 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a command to do this. However, it's a straightforward piece of scripting.

1. Work out how to identify a file by its contents and move it:

   ```
   f=example_file.txt
   b=$(head -c1 <"$f")
   [ "$b" = "0" ] && echo mv -- "$f" zero/
   ```
2. Work out how to iterate across all the 100,000 files in the directory:

   ```
   find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print
   ```

   Or maybe your shell allows you to use a wildcard for a large number of entries and the simpler more obvious loop will work:

   ```
   for f in *
   do
       echo "./$f"
   done
   ```
3. Work out how to run the `mv` code for each possible file:

   ```
   find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh -c '
       b=$(head -c1 "$1")
       [ "$b" = "0" ] && echo mv -- "$1" zero/
   ' _ {} \;
   ```

   Or

   ```
   for f in *
   do
       [ "$(head -c1 "$f")" = "0" ] && echo mv -- "$f" zero/
   done
   ```
4. Optimise the `find` version:

   ```
   find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh -c '
       for f in "$@"
       do
           [ "$(head -c1 "$f")" = "0" ] && echo mv -- "$f" zero/
       done
   ' _ {} +
   ```

In all cases remove `echo` to change the command from telling you what it would do, to doing it.

Comment: Why not use a `for` loop directly?

Comment: @StephenKitt easier to use `find -type f` than `for f in *; do [ -f "$f" ] || continue`. Some implementations may object to `*` being expanded to (or handled as) 100,000 values